# Conflicting messages in the book.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

So in one example they state the following:

> **(1):** If $X\sim \text{unif[0,1]}$ and given $X=x$ and
>   $Y\sim\text{unif}[0,x],$ what is $\rho(X,Y)?$
>
> From previous treatment of this example we know that the means are
>   $E[X]=1/2$ and $E[Y]=1/4$...

Then they proceed solving the problem. However, on the next page they have the following example

> **(2):** Let $X\sim\text{unif}[0,1]$ and given $X=x$, let $Y\sim\text{unif}[0,x^2].$ Find $E[Y|X=x]$ and $l(x).$
>
> It's clear from the description that $E[Y|X=x]=x^2/2....$

Wait...what? Can someone explain to me how they computed $E[Y]$ in example **(1)**? Shouldn't it say $E[Y|X=x]$ there too?

In **(1)** they have integrated the answer and in **(2)** they just divide the range of $Y$ by $2$. I don't see the difference here. Need some light sheded on this.

Comment: $$E[Y]=\int_0^1\color{blue}{E[Y\mid X=x]}\ dx=\int_0^1 \color{blue}{\frac x2} \ dx=\frac14.$$

Comment: I see what you did there... thanks!